# How to pass Badge Value with Redux to BottomTabBar on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reducers

How to change Badge Value on BottomTabBar using Redux ?

Value Badge on BottomTabBar with Redux (99+) there i want to change it with value from redux

[image: Value Badge on BottomTabBar with Redux (99+) there i want to change it with value from redux]

Connect

[image: connect]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new component to handle state changes

```
class Mybadge extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
         num:99
    };
//call the following function to set badge number
    functionToSetBadgeNum(num){
      this.setState({num:num})
      }
    render(){
     return (<Badge value={this.state.num} status="error" />)
     }
  }
```

Now you can add the new component instead of Badge component.

Comment: Thanks now i can put the value badge from redux !